# MessageBox - return value when box has no Cancel button

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox

according to the [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx)  documentation:

> Return value
>
> Type: int
>
> If a message box has a Cancel button, the function returns
>   the IDCANCEL value if either the ESC key is pressed or the Cancel
>   button is selected. **If the messagebox has no Cancel button, pressing
>   ESC has no effect.**

What if I wish to have a a box that ***has no Cancel button*** but I want to distinguish between OK and close/ESC?

Comment: If pressing [ESC] has no effect, what sort of distinguishing do you have in mind? If the dialog is dismissed using anything but [Enter] or the Ok button, the return value is different from `IDOK`.

Comment: @IInspectable from testing, it appear the return value is always `IDOK (1)` regardless if user hit OK or close

Comment: This sounds like a really strange and unintuitive user design. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageBox()` does not support the behavior you are looking for. You would have to hook the dialog directly, using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()`, in order to detect it being closed.

Use [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx) instead.  It has a `TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION` flag:

> Indicates that the dialog should be able to be closed using Alt-F4, Escape, and the title bar's close button even if no cancel button is specified in either the **dwCommonButtons** or **pButtons** members.

All of those conditions will return `IDCANCEL`.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I wish to have a a box that has no Cancel button but I want to distinguish between OK and close/ESC?

Standard dialogs don't offer such behaviour because it is very poor design. As a point of principle, a GUI should allow actions to be performed by mouse or keyboard. A hidden action only accessible by keyboard is a sign of poor design.

If you really want to make such a dialog, you'll have to implement it yourself. However, you should not. Present the dialog with OK and Cancel buttons.